# How can I force AOL to index the site?

Tags: search-engine-indexing

My site is fully indexed by Google, but particularly not by AOL.
What can I do to force AOL to index it all?

I have read a lot of info that AOL uses Google database.
The site is submitted to Google Webmasters, all the pings and sitemaps are configured.

Comment: How much of your traffic even comes from AOL any more...?

Comment: AOL is the only company/entity completely blocked from my site and I normally allow everyone. I am not sure why you ***want*** a company with such a bad reputation to have access to your site.

Comment: Who cares for AOL these days :)

Comment: AOL is maintainde by Google and is some way represents Google behaviour on USA market, which is main for us. When I'm tracking positions of the most competitive keywords manually, some documents are not indexed and, as a result, not ranked here to compare them with the competitors.

Answer (score 1):

Moderator's note: [AOL has been powered by Bing](https://www.windowscentral.com/aol-search-now-powered-bing-case-you-were-still-using-it-some-reason) since 2015 and [The Open Directory Project was shut down](https://www.primeinspiration.com/aol-decides-close-dmoz-19-years-time-say-good-bye.html) in 2017. Most of the rest of this answer is out of date.

---

According to [About AOL Search](http://search.aol.com/aol/about):

> These listings are administered, sorted and maintained by Google. ...
> For information on how Google sorts these listings, go to [About Google](http://www.google.com/intl/en/about.html).

AOL is likely a bit behind Google in listing these, so you should probably just give a few days extra to catch up.

---

Note that https://help.aol.com/articles/aol-search-faqs gives slightly different information under "How do I add websites to AOL Search?"

> AOL Search is a hierarchical Web directory, organized by subject. All
> user-submitted Web content is maintained by the Open Directory Project
> (`http://www.dmoz.org`). The Open Directory Project is run by a staff of
> volunteer editors who evaluate and classify websites in one or more
> categories and exercise the option of choosing to add a site, moving
> sites between categories and creating new sites.
>
> If you would like to submit a site to the Open Directory Project,
> please go to `http://www.dmoz.org/`, click suggest URL and follow the
> steps for submitting a site.The Open Directory volunteers are quite
> passionate about their work and your site will be evaluated quickly.
>
> If your site has been accepted into the Open Directory, it may take
> anywhere from two weeks to several months for your site to be listed
> on partner sites which use the Open Directory data, such as AOL
> Search, Google, Netscape Search, etc.

Comment: DMOZ is not real for usat the moment due to the reason of small amount of administartion staff to approve request, while becoming the administrator of a category to submit your own request may be not safe because of policies. Besides this, it may require a lot of time and resiurces. Despite this, thank you very much for the info!