# How can I submit my site to other search engines?

Tags: search-engines, search-engine-indexing

I just want to add my site to other search engines like aol, ask, duckduckgo etc. 
My site is ready to be indexed but I am facing problems in order to index it in other search engines. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84365/how-can-i-force-aol-to-index-the-site) tells you how you can force aol to index your site after the site is submitted to Google Webmasters, all the pings and sitemaps are configured.

For duckduckgo, it automatically indexes the web:

> No need to; DDG automatically indexes the web, so your website should be listed soon. (As DDG also uses results from Bing/Yahoo, you could try submitting it to them: http://www.bing.com/webmaster/SubmitSitePage.aspx http://www.search.yahoo.com/info/submit.html)

([Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20180910001500/https://duck.co/forum/thread/2955/how-to-submit-my-website-to-duckduckgo-com))